# How to create a mixed data buffer in Java?

Tags: java

I need to create a buffer which contains byte and string data. How can I do this in Java?

Comment: How would the two types co-exist in this buffer? Can you elaborate on how you would use this?

Comment: Any buffer based on a byte array can of course store both bytes and Strings (as bytes). Can you give more information about how you intend to use this buffer? Are the items in the buffer of fixed length and in a known order?

Comment: I m using this for iso8583xml messages, where the first byte is quotient and second byte is remainder of the lenght of the message and finally from 3rd position its a ascii string. Hence i need to send a buffer filled with bytes + string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use plain array of objects Object[] or any implementation of collections (List, Set) etc.

But why? If you want to store different types of data in the same collection, check your design. If you still wish to do this create wrapper interface and as many as you want implementations. Each implementation will store its type if data. Then create collection that stores these wrappers:

```
interface StorageCell<T> {
}

class StringCell implements StorageCell<String>{}
class ByteCell implements StorageCell<Byte>{}
```

and finally the buffer is:
`Collection<? extends StorageCell> buffer = new LinkedList<StorageCell>();`